# how to access another page element across domains

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page from which I want to load child html and get element data of across domains. What are the ways to access this content.

I can't modify child.html here

```
http://localhost:8080/child.html
<html>    
    <body>
        <div id="test">Send me a message!</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.html

```
<html>
    <load child html>
    <body>
        <script> How to access element "test" here.
    </body>
</html>
```

My question:

1. What is the good way to access cross domain pages element ID.
2. I heard iframe we can use.. but I can't post message from child.html.

Comment: Use an ajax call that accepts json data type.

Comment: If you're going across domains, you will run into [same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restrictions if you try to load as an AJAX request. Unless you have control over the source server, there is not a good way to do this.

Comment: Do you have access/control of the both pages from both domains?

Comment: i can modify main.html page but i dont have control on child.html. but i need to access the element of child.html

Comment: @NilotpalBarpujari incase of ajax call , i need to add js in child.html also. but i have no control for child.html